# Weird shadowy area in Viewport Shader

Tags: mesh, vertices, shadows, remesh

I've been using Blender for quite some time now, and I frequently encounter this issue. This issue happens when I do custom meshes and add vertices, edges or faces. There is a weird shadowy area that appear on my mesh. It is visible from the Viewport Shader, but also from Edit mode, or when I render the object. Even when I realign all the vertices in a perfect flat surface by inputing the location of each vertice manually or when I recalculate normals, it still does that. The shadow seems to be emanating from one single vertice.

Since I don't know what this issue is called, I can't search on Google to find the solution, or search this website to check if this issue has already been adressed. I tried doing some searches with several key words, such as ''shadow in viewport shader'', ''custom meshes common problems'', etc... but I couldn't find anything. Do you guys know what this issue is called, or how to fix it?[image]

[image]

Comment: I think we'll need to see an image of that area in Edit mode to see what's going on and if possible a Blend file which you can share via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there if it's not too large.

Comment: I just added the screenshot from the Edit mode. Hope it helps understanding the problem. Sorry, I can't share the blender file via blend-exchange. It's a for work and I'm under NDA.

Comment: Yes it does! You'll often get shading problems if you have lots of edges all meeting at one vertex. Any reason why you've used tris rather than quads to model your object?